# Renaming files with dir values using Ant?

Tags: ant

I have the following simple thing to do with Ant but did not find how to do that:

move `build/xxx/file.ext` to `dest/xxxfile.ext`

I'm no Ant Guru .
`file.ext` is constant in this particular case

Nota : `xxx` can take many values so I want to apply to all these values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `mapper` element to generate the destination file names.  This is derived from the [Ant `mapper` docs](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/mapper.html):

```
<move todir="dest">
    <fileset dir="build" includes="*/*.ext" />
    <mapper type="regexp" from="^([^/]*)/([^/]*)" to="\1\2"/>
</move>
```

Comment: Great thx,  although I ended up using `(.*)\\(.*)` due to some Windows incompatibilities.

Answer (score -1):

When in doubt, an [exec](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) will do the job for you, but it's not always the best way.

Try the [move](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/move.html) task.

```
<move file="build/xxx/file.ext" tofile="dest/xxxfile.ext"/>
```

Comment: `xxx` is variable depends on the actual content of `build` dir therefore I do not think it works.